# Why does Bing not show my adcenter ads though there is enough space

Tags: seo, google-adsense, microsoft

I created several campaigns using the MS adcenter. I'm targeting the whole world at any time with 2-3 placement texts per keyword group. The bids I placed are sometimes quite high, so they should get displayed.

When I try to search for my keywords in Bing nothing gets displayed, though there is plenty of space for it. Bing mostly displays 2-3 ads, but the ones at the right side rather seldom.

I'd like to know, how I can improve the fact that my ads are not being displayed - without increasing the bids any further.

Comment: Do other people see your ads? Have you tried using a proxy?

Comment: I tried using my mobile phone via 3G with the Bing desktop search - so the network is different. The result is the same.

Comment: Well, that sufficiently puzzles me :)

Comment: What I have to check though is a web connection - maybe per proxy - to make Bing think I'm in the USA … would that make any difference if I am not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From: [Microsoft Advertising](http://community.microsoftadvertising.com/) > Advertisers > adCenter Advertiser

[**Bing sponsored ads not showing**](http://community.microsoftadvertising.com/forums/t/5251.aspx)

> About finding your text ad in search
>   results
>
> To find your text ad on Bing results
>   pages, use the [Ad Preview Tool](https://adcenterhelp.microsoft.com/Help.aspx?market=en-CA&project=adCenter_live_Std&querytype=topic&query=MOONSHOT_PROC_UsingAdPreviewTool.htm). If you
>   can't find your ad, try these
>   troubleshooting tips:
>
> 1. Did you recently submit your ad group, ads, and keywords?
>
>    If you can't find a recently submitted ad in the search results,
>      wait a few hours and then check again.
>      Sometimes there is a delay between the
>      time you submitted your ad and the
>      time it is displayed.
> 2. Have you checked successive search results pages?
>
>    Be sure to check the second, third, or even fourth page of Bing
>      results.
> 3. Are your account, campaign, and ad group active?
>
>    Although you may have given us your credit card information, it's a
>      good idea to double-check your account
>      status. The Accounts & Billing page
>      shows the status of your accounts.
>
>    Select a campaign or ad group to check its status. Campaigns and ad
>      groups that are live have a status of
>      Active.
> 4. Are your ads and keywords active?
>
>    Click the Ads tab or Keywords tab to view the status of ads or
>      keywords. Ads and keywords that are
>      Active are approved and live. Ads with
>      Inactive status are not live during
>      the review process. Note that both the
>      ad and the keywords must be active. If
>      a keyword that is associated with your
>      ad is inactive or disapproved, your ad
>      will not be displayed in search
>      results.
> 5. Does your ad campaign still have budget?
>
>    Review the Change campaign settings page to see how much budget
>      you have available or whether an ad
>      group has the status Budget Paused
>      because you reached your budget limit.
>      For more information, see How campaign
>      budget limits affect ad display.
> 6. Are you dividing your campaign budget across the month?
>
>    Microsoft adCenter provides two options for spending your campaign
>      budget:
>            - Spend until depleted
>            - Divide your budget across the month
>
>    If you're using the second option, your ad is unlikely to be
>      displayed with every search. To see
>      your ad, you might have to search
>      multiple times.
> 7. Does your ad group have target settings?
>
>    If the ad group is targeted to specific geographical locations, times
>      of day, or other target settings, you
>      might not see it if you don't meet the
>      targeting criteria. For example, you
>      might be in a different city than the
>      one you're targeting.
>
>    Some web services offer public proxy servers, making it possible for
>      you to see your ads by using their
>      servers. Check the Internet for these
>      web services and instructions for how
>      to view your ads by using the specific
>      service. For more information, see
>      About targeting.
> 8. Does your search use the same keyword search match types that you
>      defined for the ad?
>
>    Make sure that your search takes into account your keyword match types:
>      broad match (The broadest keyword
>      matching option. If customers search
>      by using the words in your keyword
>      list, in any order, your ad will
>      display. Broad match can also trigger
>      displays for synonyms, plurals, and
>      related phrases, even when they're not
>      in your keyword list.) , phrase match
>      (A keyword option that considers your
>      keyword a match with a customer's
>      search query if the query includes all
>      words in the exact order given, even
>      in combination with other words. For
>      example, "toy plane" is a phrase match
>      with "toy plane" and "wooden toy
>      plane" but not with "toy wooden
>      plane.") , exact match (The most
>      focused keyword matching option. When
>      you choose exact matching for a
>      keyword, your ad will appear only when
>      that exact keyword is entered with no
>      other keywords.) , and negative
>      keywords (A specific word or phrase
>      that helps to prevent your ad from
>      being displayed to customers who are
>      unlikely to click your ad.) . For more
>      information, see About search match
>      types.
> 9. Does your search use the same language settings as your ad group
>      language and market setting?
>
>    For example, if your ad group's language and market (A set of websites
>      that is typically defined by a
>      geographical region, but can be
>      accessed by everyone regardless of
>      where they are located.) setting is
>      English - United States and you are
>      searching www.bing.com with English
>      (United Kingdom) language settings,
>      you will not see your ads. To change
>      your Bing language settings, go to
>      www.bing.com, click Options, and
>      select the correct language.
>
>    1. Does your search return any organic search results?
>
>       If a keyword does not trigger any organic search results, it will
>         not trigger paid results either. In
>         that case, try using a different
>         keyword from the same ad group.
>
> Using the Ad Preview Tool The Ad
>   Preview Tool displays a Bing search
>   results page and Microsoft adCenter
>   ads for the keyword you specify. You
>   can use the tool to see which ads are
>   being displayed for a particular
>   keyword without affecting the
>   impressions (An ad that is served to
>   and displayed on a user's browser.) or
>   CTR (Click-through rate.The ratio of
>   the number of times an ad is clicked
>   to the number of times the ad is
>   displayed. ) of your campaign.
>
> 1. Click the Tools tab, and then click Ad Preview Tool.
> 2. On the Ad Preview Tool page, type the keyword for which you want to
>      find search ads, and then click
>      Preview Ads.
> 3. If you see a security message, do one of the following:
>            * If the message says Do you want to view only the webpage content
>      that was delivered securely, click No
>      to proceed.
>            * If the message says This page contains both secure and
>      nonsecure items, click Yes to proceed.
>
> You might not see your ad on the
>   search results page in the Ad Preview
>   Tool for the following reasons:
>
> - The tool shows ads as they appear to an average searcher. So, for
>     example, if you are using targeting by
>     geographical location, and your ads
>     appear only to a small percentage of
>     searchers, these ads might not appear
>     in Ad Preview Tool.
> - You are being outbid on your keywords by other advertisers, or your
>     ad relevance is not high enough to
>     outperform ads of other advertisers.

Comment: I think the most two important things on this text are:

6. Are you dividing your campaign budget across the month?
9.1 Does your search return any organic search results?

Since everything else seems to be set correctly, those two were things that caught my attention. I think #9.1 is a rather heavy one - and I think google acts differently at this point.